# Separation of Klein-Gordon-/Dirac-equation (Bohmian-mechanics)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation, bohmian-mechanics

With the function $R{ e }^{ \frac { i }{ \hbar  } S }$ one can separate the Schrödinger equation
$$i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=\left(-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2 m} \nabla^{2}+V\right) \psi$$
into

$$\begin{aligned}
&\rightarrow \frac { \partial \rho  }{ \partial t } +\nabla \cdot (\rho v)=0\qquad\qquad\qquad \left(R={ \rho  }^{ 2 },\quad v=\frac{1}{m} \nabla S\right)&\\
&\rightarrow \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=-\left[\frac{|\nabla S|^{2}}{2 m}+V+Q\right]\qquad\qquad\left(Q=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2 m} \frac{\nabla^{2} R}{R}\right)&
\end{aligned}$$
My question is:

- Is it possible to separate the Klein-Gordon-/Dirac equation with the same function or is there a mathematical or physical reason why it's not possible?
- Is there another function or way to separate these equations to get a better feeling for the real and imaginary part (or the phase an absolut value)?

I tried to separate the Klein-Gordon-equation

\begin{equation}
\partial_{t}^{2} \psi-\nabla^{2} \psi+m^{2} \psi=0
\end{equation}

with the function $R{ e }^{ iS }$ but I am stuck with

\begin{equation}
R\left[ \left( i{ \partial  }_{ t }^{ 2 }{ S }-{ \left( { \partial  }_{ t }{ S } \right)  }^{ 2 } \right) -i\left( i\left( { S }_{ x }^{ 2 }+{ S }_{ y }^{ 2 }+{ S }_{ z }^{ 2 } \right) +{ \nabla  }^{ 2 }S \right)  \right] +{ \nabla  }^{ 2 }R+{ m }^{ 2 }R+{ \partial  }_{ t }^{ 2 }R+2i\cdot \left( { \partial  }_{ t }{ S }{ \cdot \partial  }_{ t }{ R-{ \nabla  }S\cdot { \nabla  }R } \right) =0
\end{equation}

Edit: 
The equation above leads to:
\begin{equation}
i\left[ R\left( { \partial  }_{ t }^{ 2 }S-{ \nabla  }^{ 2 }S \right) +2\cdot \left( { \partial  }_{ t }{ S }{ \cdot \partial  }_{ t }{ R-{ \nabla  }S\cdot { \nabla  }R } \right)  \right] -R\left( { \left( { \partial  }_{ t }{ S } \right)  }^{ 2 }+{ \left( { \nabla  }S \right)  }^{ 2 } \right) +{ \nabla  }^{ 2 }R+{ m }^{ 2 }R+{ \partial  }_{ t }^{ 2 }R=0
\end{equation}

Because $S,R$ are real one gets the following equations:

$$\begin{aligned}
&\rightarrow 2\cdot \left( { \partial  }_{ t }{ S }{ \cdot \partial  }_{ t }{ R-{ \nabla  }S\cdot { \nabla  }R } \right) =R\left( { { \nabla  }^{ 2 }S-\partial  }_{ t }^{ 2 }S \right) 
&\rightarrow R\left( { \left( { \partial  }_{ t }{ S } \right)  }^{ 2 }+{ \left( { \nabla  }S \right)  }^{ 2 } \right) ={ \nabla  }^{ 2 }R+{ m }^{ 2 }R+{ \partial  }_{ t }^{ 2 }R
\end{aligned}$$

The left equation yields to

\begin{equation}
2{ \partial  }_{ \mu \\  }S{ \partial  }^{ \mu  }R=R\Box S
\end{equation}

Comment: I'd guess many people had tried but failed. Because this is a natural direction once Schrödinger's is separated, but I have not seen one (caution: I am quite ignorant in this field). I'd guess it is quite close to "not possible".

Comment: Note that your change of variables didn't *separate* the equation. The variables are still pritty much coupled, in a very non-linear way.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I know but when you 'separate' the SE S and R are also nonlinearly  coupled but the two equations you get have a very well known interpretation and I am wondering if one can do the same thing with the KGE.

Answer (score 1):

Under certain reasonable condition, your first equation reduces to the continuity equation (which I call pseudo continuity equation); and your second equation gives the energy equation. I have recently posted a paper about this here: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/20/20-94.pdf . You need to jump to section 8 to see the derivation.